# How to keep a widget expanded based on user's taps?

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to create a custom widget in which when I click a button,

1. it expands to a widget something like this [ - 0 + ]
2. if the user taps '-' or '+', the button should remain expanded and should decrement or increment the value for the respective taps. The current value should be reflected.
3. if the user does not tap anything after expansion, the widget should collapse to its previous state after some x duration (say 2 seconds) from the previous tap.

Here's is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isExpanded = false;
  int quantity = 0;
  int duration = 3;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !isExpanded
        ? ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Expand (current: $quantity)'),
            onPressed: expansionHandler)
        : Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                width: 200,
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                          onPressed: decrementValue),
                      Text('$quantity'),
                      IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                          onPressed: incrementValue),
                    ])));
  }

  void incrementValue() {
    setState(() {
      duration += 3;
      quantity++;
    });
  }

  void decrementValue() {
    setState(() {
      duration += 3;
      quantity--;
      quantity = quantity < 0 ? 0 : quantity;
    });
  }

  void expansionHandler() async {
    setState(() {
      isExpanded = true;
    });
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration+3)/*not sure if this can work or not*/, () {
      setState(() {
        isExpanded = false;
        duration = 2;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

DartPad Link: https://dartpad.dev/?id=c22ea14c649cc2858f6d09270a62a0d5&null_safety=true

Comment: You want to increment the duration period on second and after that ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it's not necessary. I just want the widget to stay expanded for the x duration or if the user taps '-' or '+'.  Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Test this Widget. I comment down the `duration changes` for fast testing.
I think the problem with `expansionHandler` with Future that it is activated when you click the 1st time. On second and next click, it generates a new instance instead of replacing the current one.

According to you question, we to check the current state of Timer, where 'Future.delay' can't handle in this case.
Hope this is what you need.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isExpanded = false;
  int quantity = 0;
  int duration = 3;

  Timer? timer;

  setUpTimer() async {
    print("startTimer");
    setState(() {
      isExpanded = true;
    });
    timer = await Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: duration), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        isExpanded = false;
        duration = 2;
      });
      timer.cancel();
      print("done with time $duration");
    });
  }

  _reset() {
    if (timer != null && timer!.isActive) timer!.cancel();
    setUpTimer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (timer != null && timer!.isActive) timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !isExpanded
        ? ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Expand (current: $quantity)'),
            onPressed: _reset,
          )
        : Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 200,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                      onPressed: decrementValue),
                  Text('$quantity'),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: incrementValue,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
  }

  void incrementValue() {
    setState(() {
      // duration += 3;
      ///for fast testing

      quantity++;
    });
    _reset();
  }

  void decrementValue() {
    setState(() {
      // duration += 3;
      quantity--;
      quantity = quantity < 0 ? 0 : quantity;
    });
  }
}
```